# Finding the max sum using javascript with a twist

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am currently working on a function where it takes an array of number as input and output an int thats the biggest value added

catch: if num[i] is selected, and num[i-1] and/or num[i+1] has the same value as num[i], all neighboring numbers that has a neighbor of num[i] will be deleted.

If any element is chosen to be removed and added to the sum, then any other element equal to one of the neighbors will be removed without being added to the score.  In the first case, by removing 2 (index 1) it has a neighbor of 2, hence all 2s will be removed in one round.

for example, if we have 0,2,2,2,7,2,2,2. the output should be 2+7=9 as the other 2s will all be deleted

However, im stuck on case 3, and 5, i solved case 1,2, and 4

Any input would be appreciated

```
function findMaxScore(nums){
        var curr_max = 0;
        var countNeg = 0;

        //edge case: if all numbers are < 0, return 0
        let allNeg = nums => nums.every(n => n <= 0);
        if (nums.length === 0 || allNeg(nums)){ 
            console.log("All numbers in nums are negative or =0, thus return 0");
            return 0;}

        else{
            for (var i = 0; i<nums.length; i++){
                    //if there is a 0 in the array or a negative number, move on
                    //since they don't add any positive values
                    if(nums[i]<0 || nums[i]===0){
                        nums.splice(i,1);
                        console.log("got rid of all the 0s and negative numbers, currently num is: "+ nums);
                    }

                    var leftNeighbor = nums[i-1];
                    //console.log("left neighbor: "+leftNeighbor);
                    var rightNeighbor = nums[i+1];
                    //console.log("right neighbor: "+rightNeighbor);
                    if(leftNeighbor<=0){
                        nums.splice(i-1,1);
                    }
                    if(rightNeighbor<=0){
                        nums.splice(i+1,1);
                    }
                    curr_max+= nums[i];
                    //delete all neighboring numbers that contain the same value as i-1 and i+1
                    //if the left or ride side of subarray contains the same neighboring value, 
                    //delete that number as well
                    if(nums[i]===leftNeighbor){
                        nums.splice(i-1,1);
                        if(nums[i-2]===leftNeighbor){
                            nums = nums.filter(n => n !== leftNeighbor);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(nums[i]===rightNeighbor){
                        nums.splice(i+1,1);
                        if(nums[i+2]===rightNeighbor){
                            nums = nums.filter(n => n !== rightNeighbor);
                        }
                    }

                    if(nums.length=1){
                      curr_max+= nums[i];   
                    } return curr_max;

                    console.log("current max: "+curr_max);
                    //if no nums[i-1] or nums[i+1] is not equal to nums[i]
                    //delete the neighboring numbers
                    if((leftNeighbor!=nums[i]&&rightNeighbor!=nums[i])&&nums.length>1){
                        nums.splice(i-1,1);
                        nums.splice(i,1);
                        i++;
                        //console.log("iteration number: "+(i+1)+". num is currently at index "+(i)+", with a value of: "+nums[i]);
                        //console.log("deleting value at nums[i-1]: "+ nums[i-1]+ ",index of: "+ (i-1));
                        //console.log("deleting value at nums[i+1]: "+ nums[i]+ ",index of: "+ (i));
                        curr_max+= nums[i];
                    }

                }

        }
    /*
        //check to see if the current score is the max score
        var max_so_far = curr_max;
        for (var j = i; j< nums.length; j++){
            curr_max += (nums[j]-nums[j-1]);
            max_so_far = Math.max(curr_max,max_so_far);
        }
        return max_so_far;
        */
        return curr_max;
    }


    console.log("result one: "+findMaxScore([0,1,1,5,1,1])+", expected value 6");//1+5
    console.log("result two: "+findMaxScore([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,14,1,1])+", expected value 14");//1+14
    console.log("result three: "+findMaxScore([-3,-7,3,2,3,4,3,0])+", expected value 9");//expected 9 3+3+3
    console.log("result four: "+findMaxScore([-1,-7,-9])+", expected value 0");//expected 0
    console.log("result five: "+findMaxScore([0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])+", expected value 30");//expected 30 10+8+6+4+2
```

my output:

```
got rid of all the 0s and negative numbers, currently num is: 1,1,4,1,1
result one: 5, expected value 5
result two: 11, expected value 11
result three: 2, expected value 9
All numbers in nums are negative or =0, thus return 0
result four: 0, expected value 0
got rid of all the 0s and negative numbers, currently num is: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
result five: 2, expected value 30
```

Comment: what does a found same value deletes?

Comment: It deletes all the neighbor values that are the same value as num[i] if num[i+2] and num[i+3] are the same as num[i] and num[i+1] they will be deleted as well

Comment: but why is `1,1,4,1,1` going to be `5`? do you take `4` in the first step and then delete all ones but keep one...?

Comment: You take 1 first delete all the other 1s then take 4

Comment: in short, you take only unique value, right?

Comment: I’m not sure look at case 1,-1,3,2,3,4,3 the output should be 9(3+3+3)

Comment: It is not clear to me why in your example, the output should be 2+7 instead of 7, or 2+7+2. Either you look at the whole array at once and mark items for deletion - then any of the 2s in the array satisfy num[i-1] *or* num[I+1] . Or you go sequentially, and delete as you go, in which case after deleting any two of the 2s, the 3d should remain...

Comment: Pro-tip: iterate through the list, set each as a property in an object (it can't duplicate), get the keys of the object, parse as numbers and sum

Comment: @Gnudiff problem is it doesn’t remain. In the case of 0,1,1,4,1,1 the output should be 5(1+4)

Comment: is the task from a webpage? do you have a link to the orginal description?

Comment: "If any element is chosen to be removed and added to the sum, then any other element equal to one of the neighbors will be removed without being added to the score.  In the first case, by removing 1 (index 1) it has a neighbor of 1, hence all 1s will be removed in one round."

Comment: I have some other examples at the bottom as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The soultion gets all expected values, except the second one where it get the last commented value of `15` instead of `14`.

> How it works:
>
> It takes an iterative and recursive approach, iterative, because it iterates every item and recursive by handing over an array and a partial sum for the visited/removed values.
>
> As any working recursive function this recursive design takes an exit condition on top, where it check the remaining length of the array and take the maximum value as result and returnes the function `iter`.
>
> Then the iterative part takes place, where a value `v` is taken to the sum and the array is filtered from
>
> - the value from the left neighbor,
> - the value from the right neighbor and
> - from the value at the taken index.
>
> Then `iter` is called again with a subset and a sum.

```js
function findMaxScore(array) {
    function iter(array, sum) {
        if (!array.length) {
            max = Math.max(max, sum);
            return;
        }
        array.forEach((v, i, a) => 
            iter(
                array.filter((w, j) => w !== a[i - 1] && w !== a[i + 1] && i !== j),
                sum + v
            )
        );
    }

    var max = 0;
    iter(array.filter(v => Number.isInteger(v) && v > 0), 0);
    return max;
}

console.log("result one: " + findMaxScore([0, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1]) + ", expected value 6");//1+5
console.log("result two: " + findMaxScore([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14, 1, 1]) + ", expected value 14");//1+14
console.log("result three: " + findMaxScore([-3, -7, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 0]) + ", expected value 9");//expected 9 3+3+3
console.log("result four: " + findMaxScore([-1, -7, -9]) + ", expected value 0");//expected 0
console.log("result five: " + findMaxScore([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) + ", expected value 30");//expected 30 10+8+6+4+2
```

Comment: Can you explain what w,j,i,v all stand for

Comment: `v` is the value of an item, `i` is the index of it for `array.forEach`, as well as the filter value `w` and its index `j` of the `array.filter`. please have a look to [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and have a look to the structure of the callback for this methods.